# Python problem importing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file with this structure:

| Path name | Path ID | Phenotype data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| path name 1 | ID 1 | Table 1 |
| path name 2 | ID 2 | Table 2 |

And each table in the last cell has this structure:

| Gene_MGI_ID | Gene_ENSEMBL_ID | Phenotype list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MGI_1 | ENS_1 | [Pheno1,Pheno2,Pheno 3,...] |
| MGI_2 | ENS_2 | [Pheno5,Pheno8,Pheno 9,...] |

I'm importing the file using this code:

```
path=pd.read_csv(dir+"path_dataset.csv", header=0, index_col=0)
```

The problem is that the last column instead of being a data frame with these 3 columns, it's a single string. For example the first table once imported is represented by this string:

```
'      MGI_ID              ENS_ID                                         Pheno_list\n0  MGI:99702  ENSMUSG00000003873  [MP:0000218, MP:0000321, MP:0000571, MP:000069...'
```

How can I convert this string in the data frame described above?
Here the first three elements of the table as example of the csv file structure:

```
,Pathway,Path_ID,Pheno_data
0,response to organophosphorus,GO:0046683,"      MGI_ID              ENS_ID                                         Pheno_list
0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  [MP:0000278, MP:0000351, MP:0001156, MP:000126..."
1,response to cAMP,GO:0051591,"      MGI_ID              ENS_ID                                         Pheno_list
0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  [MP:0000278, MP:0000351, MP:0001156, MP:000126..."
2,secondary metabolite biosynthetic process,GO:0044550,"        MGI_ID              ENS_ID    Pheno_list
```

Comment: What is the separator of your csv file? You should specify it as parameter, for example: `path=pd.read_csv(dir+"path_dataset.csv", sep='\t', header=0, index_col=0)`

Comment: I saved the file with `p.to_csv("Results/path_dataset.csv", header=True, sep=",")` but also using " sep=',' " when importing, I have the same result

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your csv in the question?

Comment: @Tranbi sure, I added it at the bottom

Comment: How did you write those long multilines strings in your csv? I guess they should be separated by `,` as well...?

Comment: Those lines are a sub-dataframe stored inside the main one. I think that using `to_csv()` will automatically store those sub-dataframe as a single string since it is not able to create subtables in the file

Comment: In your example, have you split the lines or is that how it actually is?

Comment: @MartinEvans this is exactly how the csv file is structured, I didn't split the lines

Answer (score 0):

The `pheno_data` looks like a textual dump of a dataframe into a single cell. Due to the default formatting it has truncated the output, the `[` does not have a closing `]` and the last value shows `...`.

Your example is also missing the second half of the last row (no closing `"`). For the following example (where a last line has been added):

```
,Pathway,Path_ID,Pheno_data
0,response to organophosphorus,GO:0046683,"      MGI_ID              ENS_ID                                         Pheno_list
0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  [MP:0000278, MP:0000351, MP:0001156, MP:000126..."
1,response to cAMP,GO:0051591,"      MGI_ID              ENS_ID                                         Pheno_list
0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  [MP:0000278, MP:0000351, MP:0001156, MP:000126..."
2,secondary metabolite biosynthetic process,GO:0044550,"        MGI_ID              ENS_ID    Pheno_list
0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  [MP:0000278, MP:0000351, MP:0001156, MP:000126..."
```

The following script could be used to read in the values:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

data = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        sub_csv = csv.reader(io.StringIO(row[3]), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        sub_header = next(sub_csv)
        sub_row = next(sub_csv)
        pheno_list = [v.strip('[.,') for v in sub_row[3:]]
        data.append([*row[:2], *sub_row[:3], *pheno_list])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[*header[:3], *sub_header[:2], *[f'p{i}' for i in range(1, 5)]])

print(df)
```

This would give a dataframe as:

```
                                        Pathway Path_ID     MGI_ID              ENS_ID          p1          p2          p3         p4
0  0               response to organophosphorus       0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  MP:0000278  MP:0000351  MP:0001156  MP:000126
1  1                           response to cAMP       0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  MP:0000278  MP:0000351  MP:0001156  MP:000126
2  2  secondary metabolite biosynthetic process       0  MGI:96648  ENSMUSG00000071076  MP:0000278  MP:0000351  MP:0001156  MP:000126
```

If you get problems reading your file in, try adding `print(row)` to see at which point it fails.

---

To keep the pheno types as a single entry, change these two lines:

```
data.append([*row[:2], *sub_row[:3], ', '.join(pheno_list)])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[*header[:3], *sub_header[:3]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just a question: it is possible to have the phenotypes (the columns you called p1,p2,...) all in a single column as a list? Or do I have to separate them like in your example?

Comment: They could be joined into a single string value, I have added an example